# Failure reports in timed triggers in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I use the following timed trigger on a Google Spreadsheet. It runs every ten minutes:

```
    function timedTriggerWatchFiles(rootFolder) {
  // make an array with all the names of the childfolder
  if (DriveApp.getFoldersByName(rootFolder).hasNext()) {
    var childFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(rootFolder).next().getFolders();
  }
  var childFoldersA = [];
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    childFoldersA.push(childFolders.next().getName());
  }
   // run watchfiles for each child folder
  for ( var i=0 ; i < childFoldersA.length ; i++) {
    watchFiles(rootFolder, childFoldersA[i]);
  }
}

function timedTrigger() {
timedTriggerWatchFiles("folder");
}
```

At least once a day I get a 'failure report' in my Inbox, saying:

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit 
and try again. (line 242, file "Code")
```

The execution log gives the following message:

```
[14-01-22 17:29:38:363 CET] Execution failed: We're sorry,
a server error occurred.    Please wait a bit and try again. 
(line 242, file "Code") [37.016 seconds total runtime]
```

The lines are always different, but also always contain the function `hasNext()`. This is line 242:

```
 while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
```

What am I doing wrong here? My script works as it is supposed to work. I just don't understand why I am receiving the error messages.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `Utilities.sleep(1000);`  in your while loop to prevent over calling the API?

Comment: I tried adding that in my while loop and it seems to work. I haven't received any errors since I changed the code. I do wonder, however, why the error code isn't any clearer. Thank you. If you make this into an answer, I can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Greg's answer points to all the right resources for working with APIs in Google Apps Scripts.

Although it may appear that access to things like `ScriptDB`, `DriveApp`, `SpreadsheetApp` etc is native to Apps Scripts, in fact there are access limitations for aggressive use. The simplest of solutions is `Utilities.sleep(1000);`.

However, if you have a script that is running tightly within the 600 second limit, or you need to ensure that every request is made as quickly as possibly, then the resources in @Greg's answer will be of great assistance.

Answer (score 2):

In the Drive SDK documentation there is a section about [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors#implementing_exponential_backoff) that you should check out. You could try the [GASRetry](https://gist.github.com/peterherrmann/2700284) library to simplify this in Apps Script.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening article. I, however, tried the solution @fooby proposed, and it seemed to have worked. Why do you think a randomized `sleep()` variable would have been useful in this case?