# Adding GASRetry Library in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using GASRetry inside my google script. when I am trying to run its showing the GASRetry is undefined. May I know how to add the GASRetry library in my project? From where can I get the script ID  of the GASRetry library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you learned about the GASRetry library? P.S. link to answer that mentions GasRetry -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/21312823/1595451. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries?hl=en#add_a_library_to_your_script_project

Answer (score 0):

I think the script id is "1EugqzsWbWssuYne0wNZvNgeXqFfD8dPRMZM3PnpaV3SsiW5qUANNxhXL" I found it [here](https://sites.google.com/site/nnillixxsource/Herrmann/GASRetry).  Went to the public script and looked at the script id in the legacy editor.